# Workbook_Open event in Excel Add ins works only for first file opening

Tags: excel, vba

Workbook_Open event in Excel Add-ins works only for the first file but If I open next files keeping the first file is open it is not functioning, Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue?

I have used this below code in Thisworkbook module to create Add-in and selected Add-In name in options also

Code:

```
Sub Workbook_Open()
    MsgBox "Welcome..!!"
End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated..!!
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work for the first file opening.

`ThisWorkbook` represents the document that's hosting the VBA code - in this case, the add-in "workbook": this message box will pop when *the add-in* is opened, when Excel starts up.

If you want to run code whenever *any* workbook is opened, you need to handle events at the `Application` level.

Declare a `WithEvents` variable in your `ThisWorkbook` module:

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents AppEvents As Excel.Application
```

Assign that object reference on open:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set AppEvents = Me.Application
End Sub
```

Now select `AppEvents` from the left-side dropdown at the top of the code pane, and pick the `WorkbookOpen` event on the right-side dropdown - that will create a handler that looks like this:

```
Private Sub AppEvents_WorkbookOpen(Wb As Workbook)

End Sub
```

If you put `MsgBox Wb.FullName` here, you should get a message box with the newly opened workbook's path/filename every time a workbook is opened.